# CSS: Menu breaks on image for background website in IE/Opera

Tags: css

I'm inexperienced with CSS, and I'm having a problem with a breaking menu on a site I'm working on at www.quickcms.ie/marywrynne/index.html. It works fine in Safari/Chrome and Firefox, but it's not working in Internet Explorer.

Can anyone suggest steps I can take to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase the height of the div where you have this css:

```
#menu div {
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #333366;
height:76px; /* increase the height of this */
opacity:0.6;
padding:7px 0 0 7px;
}
```